# Payment to make a node featured

Tags: commerce

I want users of a particular role to pay for featured nodes. On my site, the user role "premium member" is able to create nodes of type "products," but they have to pay to make their node (product) featured--for this I have a CCK checkbox field which will be checked on payment.

I am using moneyscript module for subscriptions, but I do not understand how to use it for my requirements.

I am thinking about using a custom module, but I'm also not understanding where to start and what should be the approach.

Comment: What exactly is a "featured" node?  Is this the same thing as "Sticky at the top of lists," the built-in Drupal feature?

Comment: Moneyscript is paid right ?

Comment: @Patrick, featured node will be highlighted on different sections on site like featured products, will be at top of products list etc and member have to pay to highlight his product

Comment: How many payments do you expect to handle?  Does this need to be completely automatic or is some administrator labor OK?

Comment: one payment per node, it can be automatic or require admin labor, my requirement is just to provide facility to user to make payments to highlight their products on site.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using the MoneyScripts "Membership Suite" module? You'll want to install the [Rules contrib module](https://drupal.org/project/rules), which will allow you to modify content (your node's CCK field) when a payment is made:

> New Rules Integration allows you to take action when users purchase a new membership, make a payment, cancel their membership, etc! The possibilities are limitless!